# Show scrollbar while resizing the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, window-resize

I want to show windows scrollbar when user resizes the window less than a specified width. For that i used min-width but that doesnt work with IE6. Is there any way i can do that using javascript or jquery

Answer (score 0):

try this if it will solve the problem just replace height and width in the css

```
div.scroll
{
background-color:#00FFFF;
width:100px;
height:100px;
overflow:scroll;
}
```

Comment: no.. This is not my question and it will show scrollbar all the time.

Comment: ok as i could understand now when you resize the window using jquery or javascript you want the scrollbars to be visible? is that?

Comment: It is a simple div inside the page. I want to show the windows scrollbar